# How to route tasks to queues while using Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, celery

I’m setting up multiple workers which execute tasks based on given queues with in a docker environment. I'm unable to see queues that I have declared in settings.py

I've seen that the worker command that is on the top(in container command) is only getting executed and the rest are not being executed.

This is how I'm trying to route celery tasks in settings.py

```
# Celery settings


CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:secret@redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:secret@redis:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {

    'app1.tasks.*': {'queue': 'emails'},
    'app2.tasks.*': {'queue': 'parser'},
    'app3.tasks.task1': {'queue': 'sms'}
}
```

This is how Im writing my tasks.py file.

```
@app.task(bind=True,  queue='parser')
def parser(self, extension,  data, file):
    return True
```

This is how Im giving commands in my docker-compose.yml file in a container

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command:  bash -c 'python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput  &&
                       python3 manage.py migrate --noinput &&
                       celery -A app worker -l info -Q email-n worker1 &&
                       celery -A app worker -l info -Q parser-n worker2 &&
                       celery -A app worker -l info -Q sms-n worker3 &&
                       celery -A app  worker -l info  &&
                       celery -A app beat -l info  &&
                       python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:1337'
​
​
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    expose:
      - 1337
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY = qbsdk08)5&n*x4xdya7fbm0&lb)x!6!f_#ta(y-)*!w_wibc4c
      - SQL_ENGINE = django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
      - SQL_DATABASE = postgres
      - SQL_USER = admin
      - SQL_PASSWORD = password
      - SQL_HOST = postgres_container
      - SQL_PORT = 5432
      - DATABASE = postgres
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = api.settings
    depends_on:
      - postgres_container
```

Expected Result:
Im expecting list of queues to be displayed in console and run well

Actual Result:
It displays only the first task in as given in docker-compose file in my case the below command as per docker-compose file, and the rest wont work.

"celery -A app worker -l info -Q email-n worker1 &&"

Tech:
Django v2.2
Celery v4
Redis v5

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the startup command.  You've essentially started each worker serially, so `celery -A app worker -l info -Q parser-n worker2` won't execute until after worker1 exits.  The easiest way to fix this is just to have separate docker instances for each worker.

```
  email-n:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command:  bash -c 'python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput  &&
                       python3 manage.py migrate --noinput &&
                       celery -A app worker -l info -Q email-n worker1'
...
  parser-n:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: celery -A app worker -l info -Q parser-n worker2 
  sms-n:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: celery -A app worker -l info -Q sms-n worker3 
  celery:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: celery -A app  worker -l info
  beat:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: celery -A app beat -l info
  api:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:1337
```

Alternatively, you can start one worker with multiple queues, e.g., `-Q parser-n,email-n,sms-n`.  Finally, you can also daemonize docker inside your container but then you have to have a graceful way to stop daemonization when you are ready to stop the container, but that is outside the scope of this question.